# Swing Java and anonymous classes accessing class attributes from outer classes

Tags: java, swing, visibility

***EDIT***: I've found that the following code works. It appears there was a slip-up with the earlier code. However, I still have the burning question, of whether this code is good practice? Is this an acceptable method to share the model data underlying the Swing objects between the main application thread and the Swing event dispatch thread?

```
package com.guitest;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test().run();
}

public void run() {
    Board board = new Board();
    board.createBoard();
    board.setTileValue(2, 2, 3);
    board.revalidate();
    board.repaint();
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Board extends JFrame {
    final int tileSize = 100;
    final int numberOfRows = 2;
    final int numberOfCols = 3;
    private final Map<Integer, Integer> _tiles;
    public Board() {
        _tiles = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(numberOfRows*numberOfCols));
        for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; row++) {
            for (int col = 1; col <= numberOfCols; col++) {
                _tiles.put(row*numberOfCols+col, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setTileValue(int row, int col, int value) {
        _tiles.put(row*(numberOfCols-1)+col, value);
    }

    public void createBoard() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                setLayout(new GridLayout(numberOfRows, numberOfCols, 0, 0));
                for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; row++) {
                    for (int col = 1; col <= numberOfCols; col++) {
                        add(createPanelFor(row, col));
                    }
                }
                setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                setSize(numberOfCols*tileSize, numberOfRows*tileSize);
                setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public JPanel createPanelFor(final int row, final int col) {
        return new JPanel() {
            @Override protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                g.setColor((col % 2 == 0) == (row % 2 == 0) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                String string = String.valueOf(_tiles.get(row*numberOfCols+col));
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.drawString(string, getHeight() / 2, getWidth() / 2);
            }
        };
    }
}
}
```

Comment: thoughts: mostly that it's hard to tell without complete information. Most "drawing code runs but stuff doesn't show up" end up being things running in something other than the event dispatch thread; if you haven't checked that (or don't know what it is), then it's the first thing to do. Your invokeLater() call is one way to ensure UI changes are made in the EDT.

Comment: An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Comment: I think you would get more results on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for your question